# Angular 2 - application does not find its node module directory

Tags: angular

I copied my angular project to a wamp server (except the modules directory)

I ran npm install, worked fine but now if I run the index in the browser, the node_modules are out of the src folder giving 404

( my project is based on angular 2 tutorial seed - systemJS )

```
project folder
    node_modules
    src
        index.html
```

index.html :

```
...
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

as one can see, the main index.html holds references to node_modules that should be at the same level, but in the project folder node_modules is in the parent folder

- how does it even work under light server while node_modules should be in "src" folder?
- how to make it work on a server running apache (I guess so far I would have to move the folder manualy) ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIxNH.png)

here is the package.json :
no matter any command I run it does not create me some sort of dist directory that would be usable on production

```
{
  "name": "angular-catalog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Catalog",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

thanks

[edit: I had to comment the <base...> tag in the html file and move the node_modules to src folder to make it work... I dont get it, why is it so badly implemented, what am I missing here ???]

Comment: You need to take a look on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `node_module` shouldn't be inside the `src` folder at all.

Comment: please, provide some code, and more explainations, are you using systemJS, webpack, angular-cli. How are you importing your modules ? No answer can be given without these informations.

Comment: hope this is better

Comment: @n00dl3 can you have a look ?

Comment: I am checking webpack official angular doc, but it's really out of my angular knowledge

Comment: thanks people for the wonderfull open-minded support...as usual